# Castle Windsor: unit test component lifecycle

Tags: unit-testing, castle-windsor

I would like to write a non-regression test to validate that transient components are well released. Some are created by a direct injection in ctor, other by typed factories.
I thought that I could do this way:

```
// Given
var rootComponent = container.Resolve<IRootComponent>();
var c1 = rootComponent.C1;
var c2 = c1.C2;
etc.

Assert.True(Container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(c1));
Assert.True(Container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(c2));

// When
c1.Close();

// Then
Assert.False(Container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(c1));
Assert.False(Container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(c2));
```

HasTrack() always returns **false**, although if I look at the container in debug mode, I can see my components well tracked. Why is that? Do you have any suggestion for such a test?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your components are not tracked is that the component and it's dependencies have no decomissioning requirements. In this case there is no reason for windsor to track them.

When using windsor in general you should only resolve on your container once to obtain your top level component. All other component are either injected or created by a factory. There is no need to worry about the live time of injected components. The container will handle it for you.

For transient components that you create with a factory you should be aware that they will never live (be tracked) longer then the factory it self. So if you don't mind that your components live at long as your factory there is no need to release them (using a destroy method on a factory).

For component that I want to make sure that I release them, I generally I create unit test for which I stub out the factory. That way it is easy to test that destroy is called.

I think with the approach that you are taking you are not just testing your code but also the container. IMHO windsor is already well tested, and test should focus on your own code.

Good luck,
Marwijn.

Comment: I understand your point of view. But I have at least 10 major components to track. Some are created through typed factories and therefore must be released in the source code: this is a potential bug that is not under the responsability of Windsor. Some work has been done to ensure that everything works fine and I would feel more comfortable if I could have such a UT...

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late, but here's a test.

```
public class DependsOnSomethingDisposable
{
    private readonly SomethingDisposable _disposable;

    public Boolean SomethingDisposableIsDisposed { get { return _disposable.Disposed; } }
    public DependsOnSomethingDisposable(SomethingDisposable disposable)
    {
        _disposable = disposable;
    }
}

public class SomethingDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public Boolean Disposed { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposed = true;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class WindsorLifestyleTests
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TransientDependencyIsDisposed()
    {
        _container.Register(
            Component.For<DependsOnSomethingDisposable>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<SomethingDisposable>().LifestyleTransient()
            );
        var resolved = _container.Resolve<DependsOnSomethingDisposable>();
        _container.Release(resolved);
        Assert.IsTrue(resolved.SomethingDisposableIsDisposed);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NonTransientDependencyIsNotDisposed()
    {
        _container.Register(
            Component.For<DependsOnSomethingDisposable>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<SomethingDisposable>().LifestyleSingleton()
            );
        var resolved = _container.Resolve<DependsOnSomethingDisposable>();
        _container.Release(resolved);
        Assert.IsFalse(resolved.SomethingDisposableIsDisposed);
    }
}
```